# Router and refresh multiples ng-inludes

Tags: angularjs

I start with code:

```
when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/admin/layout.html',
    controller: AdminCtrl
})
when('/admin/products', {
    templateUrl: '????',
    controller: AdminProductsCtrl
})
```

Template "tree":

```
index.html ---> <div ng-view/>
---layout.html ---> <div ng-include=menu/> and <div ng-include=body/>
------menu.html 
------products.html
```

Actually I do this:

```
function AdminCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.menu = 'partials/admin/menu.html';
}

function AdminProductsCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.menu = 'partials/admin/menu.html';
    $scope.body = 'partials/admin/products/index.html';
}
```

The point is: What I put in '????', if I put layout.html this work fine, but I like just "refresh" ng-include=body. I think that my concepts about Angularjs is wrong.

Other problem is, when AdminProductsCtrl "take the control" of layout.html I miss the AdminCtrl $scope, this implicates repeat all AdminCtrl $scope in AdminProductsCtrl $scope (for example $scope.menu).

Thanks a lot, and sorry for "my english".

**UPDATE**

After think.. and think... I understanding that routes not apply for my app, then I manage all functionality under one url 'site.com/#/admin'. The menu.html is manage for AdminMenuCtrl, this controller contains a model for each 'ng-include' and contains one method for each menu entry. When the user click a menu entry, the associate method in the $scope replace $scope.includes.body with the 'new' html. The partial cointains your ng-controller.

This works fine by now :D. And the best is that I don't need use $rootScope.

The new problem is a bit more complicated, the ng-include require a tag (i.e DIV) and ng-controller too. Then my design is affected for this. In code language:

DESING:

```
<div>MENU-HTML</div>
<div>BODY-HTML</div>
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div ng-include="menu"></div>
<div ng-include="body"></div>
```

AFTER RETRIEVE PARTIALS:

```
<div ng-include="menu"><div ng-controller="MenuCtrl">MENU-HTML</div></div>
<div ng-include="body"><div ng-controller="ListProductsCtrl">BODY-HTML</div></div>
```

THE IDEAL THING:

1 - ng-include don't 'include' into the DIV, instead 'replace' the DIV.

2 - ng-controller DIV is replaced for nothing in the DOM.

It's possible now with angular? Is a bad approach this idea? The point 2 with $route is possible, not with ng-controller directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct in your example you would set `????` to `layout.html` but the idea is to have different views based on the route so pointing to the same `layout.html` is not ideal.

If you are trying to keep a static menu on all pages I would add the menu to your `index.html` and then choose a different templateUrl for each route (ie `/admin` goes to `partials/admin.html` and `/admin/products` goes to `partials/products.html`) and not use the ngInclude.

I'm new to AngularJS but I'm getting the impression that you generally want to use ngView with routes to templateUrls OR use ngInclude (possibly with [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)) if you want to roll your own view switching. I'm sure there are times when using both is appropriate but as a newbie it confuses me somewhat. Resident experts please correct me if I'm wrong!

For your second issue there might be some helpful information [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/XwFp-6mSV2g/discussion) and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/S30ixG28ip4/discussion) for tips on sharing the same model across multiple controllers but you probably don't need to for your example.

An alternative is to use a string constant path to your partial in layout.html and remove the references to `$scope.menu` in your controller code by using:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/admin/menu.html'"/>
```

Comment: Hi @gloopy, thanks for your time. The menu.html varies according the menu option selected, some cases is hidden. I update the answer. I will read the links, thanks!

Comment: Hi think I am trying something similar to you with multiple controllers and includes. Try moving the controller div out of your partial and putting it outside of your include (like <div ng-controller="..."><div ng-include="..."/></div>) and then use your controller code to update the include source when you want to switch it out.

Comment: I can't do it, because each partial have your own controller.